# How to Parse JSON which been parse by postgreSql json_agg function

Tags: java, json, jersey

input look something like this, its an string

"[{\"lid\":874,\"id\":872,\"name\":\"Animalia\",\"canonical_form\":\"Animalia\",\"rank\":0}, \n {\"lid\":874,\"id\":874,\"name\":\"Arthropoda\",\"canonical_form\":\"Arthropoda\",\"rank\":1}]",

The outPut i want should look sth like this.

> [{"lid":874,"id":872,"name":"Animalia","canonical_form":"Animalia","rank":0},
>      {"lid":874,"id":874,"name":"Arthropoda","canonical_form":"Arthropoda","rank":1}]

Inside the getter function i try to implement but its not working properly. I am using hibernate and jersey.
The getter function i implement look like this.

```
@Column(name = "default_hierarchy")
    public ArrayList getDefaultHierarchy() {
        ArrayList<Long> data=new ArrayList<Long>();
        data=JSON.parse(this.defaultHierarchy1);
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question, it is not clear what problem you are facing and the solution required. A bit more clarity would be good.

Comment: Could it be just a matter of replacing '\"' with bare unescaped '"', something like `input.replace("\\"", "\"")`?